# How to replace all instances of a substring but only whole worlds in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, mathcontext

For example this function

```
function replaceAll(str,x,y){
    return str.split(x).join(y);
}

var x="My cat have a hat a its head.";

replaceAll(x,"at","on")
```

will return from this

> My cat have a hat at its head.

to this

> My con have a hon on its head.

but i want to return with

> My cat have a hat on its head.

Comment: Why you don't replace it manually ???

Comment: this just an example i want the analogy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function like this with word boundary regex:

```
function replaceAll(str,x,y){
    return str.split(new RegExp("\\b"+x+"\\b")).join(y);
}
```

Then:

```
repl = replaceAll(x,"at","on")
//=> My cat have a hat on its head.
```